# Merge vertex list in gremlin orientDb

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, gremlin, traversal

I am a newbie in the graph databases world, and I made a query to get leaves of the tree, and I also have a list of Ids. I want to merge both lists of leaves and remove duplicates in a new one to sum property of each. I cannot merge the first 2 sets of vertex

```
g.V().hasLabel('Group').has('GroupId','G001').repeat(
    outE().inV()
).emit().hasLabel('User').as('UsersList1')

.V().has('UserId', within('001','002')).as('UsersList2')

.select('UsersList1','UsersList2').dedup().values('petitions').sum().unfold()
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong in your query:

- you call `V().has('UserId', within('001','002'))` for every user that was found by the first part of the traversal
- the traversal could emit more than just the leafs
- `select('UsersList1','UsersList2')` creates pairs of users
- `values('petitions')` tries to access the property `petitions` of each pair, this will always fail

The correct approach would be:

```
g.V().has('User', 'UserId', within('001','002')).fold().
  union(unfold(),
        V().has('Group','GroupId','G001').
            repeat(out()).until(hasLabel('User'))).
  dedup().
  values('petitions').sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but I think the following will do:

```
g.V().union(
    hasLabel('Group').has('GroupId','G001').repeat(
        outE().inV()
    ).until(hasLabel('User')),
    has('UserId', within('001','002')))
.dedup().values('petitions').sum()
```

In order to get only the tree leaves, it is better to use `until`. Using `emit` will output all inner tree nodes as well. 
`union` merges the two inner traversals.